# Distance/absolute error between two numbers

Tags: python, numpy, distance

What is the cleanest way to get the distance between a maximum and a minimum?

1. Maximum is always bigger than the minimum (more to the right on a 1d axis, not by absolute value).
2. Maximum and minimum can be any combination of signs (positive and negative) as long as the condition 1 is satisfied

**Example**

```
max =  1  min = -1  ->  dist = 2 
max =  2  min =  1  ->  dist = 1 
max = -1  min = -2  ->  dist = 1
```

Comment: isn't that a substraction?

Comment: Yes, at the moment I didn't see it that way. I was all in norms and vectors and missed the obvious. Will vote for closure/deletion.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic math.


Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surely `abs(max - min)` would work. In fact, if the maximum is always bigger then `max - min` would work.

Answer (score 3):

If condition 1. fulfilled, you don't even need the `abs`

```
dist = max-min
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with `abs(max - min)`:

```
def diff(mx, mn):
    return abs(mx - mn)

print(diff(1, -1))
print(diff(2, 1))
print(diff(-1, -2))
```

Output:

```
2
1
1
```